# Remove blank options in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown which i create dynamically through javascript.Out of the blue a blank option gets added at 0th position.Now i wanted to remove this blank option through javascript.The only road block i m facing is checking the blank option.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<title>Dynamic DropDownList</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">



function AddItemInList()

{

    var list =  document.getElementById('DropDownList1');

    var box =  document.getElementById('Text1');

    var newListItem = document.createElement('OPTION');



    newListItem.text = box.value;

    newListItem.value = box.value;

    list.add(newListItem);



    box.value = "";

    box.focus(); 



}

function RemoveItemInList()

{

    var list  = document.getElementById('DropDownList1');

    if(list.options.length > 0)

    {

        for(var i = list.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)

        {

            if(list.options[i].selected)

            {

                list.remove(i);

                return false;

            }

        }

    }

    else

    {

        alert('Unable to remove. List is Empty!');

    }



}



</script>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">

    </asp:DropDownList>

    <input id="Text1" type="text" />

    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add New"  onclick="AddItemInList();"/>

    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Remove Item"  onclick="return RemoveItemInList();"/>

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: My html could be like this <select id="dropdown"><option></option><option>Hello</option><option>John</option>.the problem here is i dont have the id of text

Comment: "dropdown" is considered as your id. you will write like  var list  = document.getElementById('dropdown'); in your javascript.

Comment: But then how do u check whether first option is blank with above code

Comment: well i got the solution  Here is it                                var drdown= document.getElementById("dd");
        if(drdown.options[0].text =="")
        {
          var oOption = drdown.options[0];
          drdown.removeChild(oOption);
        }